# Move existing subscription items between subscription groups

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have two existing subscription groups in iTunes connect which is in released state from last 3 years. Now, i want to combine all the subscription items into a single subscription group without impacting the users who has already subscribed.

But, i don't see an option to move these subscription items between groups.

My question here is how could we efficiently combine these subscription items from diffrent group into a single group?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you can move subscriptions between groups. Subscriptions are  connected to the group. Look at the subscription groups as to [part of subscriptions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev75708c031). If you need to create new subscription group, you should create new subscriptions.
As solution, you can show in the application only one subscription and handle different subscription as same subscription.